# Custom style to Google Map V3 overlays

Tags: google-maps, overlay

I want to draw rectangles and polygon overlays on a map, but with more style than just a color and opacity. I'd like to add dotted lines for the boundary and line patterns in the polygon itself.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add most any style to the polylines and polygons. Take a gander at the google API documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineOptions